# New to programming, Problems with classes, need help to show where im going wrong

Tags: c++, visual-c++

---

### i forgot to include string header file

I'm trying to make a simple CharacterCreating and getting info program, to familiarize with classes.

I managed to get/set the info when "Character" was a struct rather than a class but I knew that I cannot have info of more than one character in it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
    public:
        //short Cid;
        string Name;
        short Race;
        short Class;
        short Age;      
};

class CharacterInitialize : public Character
{
    public:
        void SetName(Character*)
        {
            cout << "Enter Name Of Your Character: ";
            cin.getline(Name, 40);
        }
        void SetAge(Character*)
        {
            cout << "Enter The Age Of Your Character: ";
            cin >> Age;
        }
        void SetClass(Character*)
        {
            cout << "Enter Your Character's Class \n 1.Archer\n 2.Warrior\n 3.Mage";
            cin >> Class;
        }
        void SetRace(Character*)
        {
            cout << "Enter Your Character's Race \n 1. Elf\n 2. Human\n 3.Gaint";
            cin >> Race;
        }
};

class CharacterInfo : public Character
{
    public:
        void GetName(Character*)
        {
            cout << Name;
        }
        void GetAge(Character*)
        {
            cout << Age;
        }
        void GetClass(Character*)
        {
            switch (Class)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Archer";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Warrior";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Mage";
                break;
            }
        }
        void GetRace(Character*)
        {
            switch (Race)
            {
            case 1: 
                cout << "Elf";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Human";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Gaint";
                break;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to store info of many characters in classes?

Also, how do I use enums to store the data for "Classes" and "Races",

and how to get the string input? I heard cin only gets 1 character, is cin.getline the only (and correct) way?

Edited New Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Character
{
    public:
        //short Pid;
        string Name;
        short Race;
        short Class;
        short Age;

        void SetName()
        {
            cout << "Enter Name Of Your Character: ";
            getline(cin, Name);
        }
        void SetAge()
        {
            cout << "Enter The Age Of Your Character: ";
            cin >> Age;
        }
        void SetClass()
        {
            cout << "Enter Your Character's Class \n 1.Archer\n 2.Warrior\n 3.Mage";
            cin >> Class;
        }
        void SetRace()
        {
            cout << "Enter Your Character's Race \n 1. Elf\n 2. Human\n 3.Gaint";
            cin >> Race;
        }
        void GetName()
        {
            cout << Name;
        }
        void GetAge()
        {
            cout << Age;
        }
        void GetClass()
        {
            switch (Class)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Archer";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Warrior";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Mage";
                break;
            }
        }
        void GetRace()
        {
            switch (Race)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Elf";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Human";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Gaint";
                break;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    Character User;
    User.SetName();
    User.GetName();
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any problems in this one?

Comment: Why are you making the base class members public, and then implementing member functions in derived classes to act on those members?   No need for bundle sets of operations up in different classes.

Comment: You are getting nouns and verbs mixed up. Write one class, `Character`, and give it **member functions** for setting and getting variables. And tackle problems one at a time, not in bundles.

Comment: @Peter I'm testing how classes work, so i thought it would be better if i split them at first then try to combine them in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't include the "string" header file.

Answer (score -2):

```
                    #include <iostream>
                    #include <string>
                    using namespace std;

                    int main ()
                    {
                         string mystr;
                         cout << "What's your name? ";
                         getline (cin, mystr);
                         cout << "Hello " << mystr << ".\n";
                         cout << "What is your favorite team? ";
                         getline (cin, mystr);
                         cout << "I like " << mystr << " too!\n";
                         return 0;
                    }

                        here its for taking strings in cin
```

Comment: Oh, i must've got confused with something else. Thanks!

Any suggestion on classes?

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Answer (score -3):

```
  you have done this
  class Character
  {
     public:
      //short Cid;
      string Name;
      short Race;
      **short Class;**
      short Age;      
   };

   class is an predefined word for the language u cannot use it like this
   please change and try it.
```

Comment: the C is capital, i guess that won't be a problem.

Comment: that is the problem Class is keyword, capitals are reserved for languages

Comment: Oh,

I changed some things and it works, i'll try to prevent similar problems next time.

Comment: @MathanRajan This answer is simply incorrect. (See this: http://ideone.com/ZS89h4) You must have changed something else to make your code work.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. The symbols `class` and `Class` are different. The latter has no predefined meaning and can be used in client code. The talk about capitals being reserved is complete bogus. Since 3 members of this site had to waste reputation on this proposed answer, to rightfully down-vote it, it would only be fair to remove it altogether. Doing so will earn you a nice badge, too.